# SAMKeychain Delete All Account

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, keychain

I'm using this library to manage username and password by saving them in the keychain. I'm having some problems to delete service accounts. Does anyone use this library?
How can I delete all the accounts of a service at a stroke?

For now I can only delete one account at a time but I would like to have the option to delete all accounts in one go ...

This is the code I use for delete an account

```
 SAMKeychainQuery *query = SAMKeychainQuery.new;
 query.service = service;
 query.account = account;
 [query deleteItem:nil];
```

Comment: did your try `deletePasswordForService` method?

Comment: @Kuldeep  yes .. with NSArray for al account but not delete